# How should be the regex for alphanumeric where alphabet only with combinations of"w" or "d" or "h"

Tags: c#, regex

I need the regex to validate the user entered string, the string may be of following formats.

ex: `1w 2d 1h` or `2w 1h` or `1w 2d`. Likewise combinations of numbers and w,d and h.

I am looking for the regex to allow the combinations number and `w` or `d` or `h`.

Is it possible to have a regex like that way?

Comment: You should try to do it first, and show us your results, even if it's not working :)

Comment: `\d+w\s\d+d\s\d+h|\d+w\s\d+d`

Comment: I don't see a way to do this using pure regex.  Maybe try splitting on space, and then verify each component separately.

Comment: So you want any combination?

Comment: Thank all for the quick response...

Comment: @TheGeneral ,yes I want any combination of number with w, d, and h...

Comment: Do you want any order? or w -> d -> h

Comment: @TheGeneral, yes id w and d exist, the w should come first, it  should come in an order of w d h `week day hour`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `^(?:\d+w ?)?(?:\d+d ?)?(?:\d+h)?$`

Explaantion:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`w`, `d`, `h` - match literally `w`, `d`, `h` respectively

`?` - match preceeding pattern zero or one time

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IbY0eB/1)

Comment: This would match things like `1w2d3h`, with no spaces, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQxM6Z/1).  Check the answer by @ohaal for a correct regex approach.

Comment: @sahithi See Tim Biegeleisen commen.

Answer (score 3):

You could say you want

- `\d+` any number, 1 or more times
- `[wdh]` one of w, d, h
- `(?: |$)` space or end of string

Then put this in a group, loop it 1 or more times

- `(?:` start of non-capture group
- `)+` end of non-capture group, 1 or more times
- `^` and `$` start and end of string respectively

Result

```
^(?:\d+[wdh](?: |$))+$
```

Edit: I see you've added more requirements in the comments of your question, this regex will not fulfil your most recent requirements

Comment: Thanks for the way, I will try to make it as of my requirement :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can try writing a rudimentary parser to check the input string.

```
string input = "1w 2d 1h";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+");
bool success = true;

if (parts.Length > 3)
{
    success = false;
}
else
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(?:w|d|h)");
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(part);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
}

if (success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MATCH");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NO MATCH");
}
```

This answer might carry its own weight if, in your C# application, you also needed to extract the numerical values of each component.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the following string seems to be working fine for me...

```
^(?:\d+w)?((?:\d+d)|(?: \d+d))?((?:\d+h)|(?: \d+h))?$
```

Thanks, everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your requirement. Hope this helps! Ordering (*w->d->h*) guaranteed.

```
^(\d+w){0,1}\s*(\d+d){0,1}\s*(\d+h){0,1}$
```

Test cases:

10w 12d 11h

1w 2d

2w 1h

1d 1h

1d 1h

3w 2h